# Conditionally merge 2 text files using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, merge, conditional-statements

I'm currently trying to merge the 2 following text files:

```
//POINTER #3 @ $3A2C - STRING #3 @ $3C85
#W32($3A2C)
//・同行人の死亡[NLINE]
//・パーティーの全滅[END-FE]


//POINTER #4 @ $3A30 - STRING #4 @ $3CAA
#W32($3A30)
//・パーティーの全滅[END-FE]
```

```
//POINTER #3 @ $3BAC - STRING #3 @ $3E17
#W32($3BAC)
・Follower dies[NLINE]
・All party members die[END-FE]


//POINTER #4 @ $3BB0 - STRING #4 @ $3E42
#W32($3BB0)
・All party members die[END-FE]
```

After merging it should look like this:

```
//POINTER #3 @ $3A2C - STRING #3 @ $3C85
#W32($3A2C)
//・同行人の死亡[NLINE]
//・パーティーの全滅[END-FE]
・Follower dies[NLINE]
・All party members die[END-FE]

//POINTER #4 @ $3A30 - STRING #4 @ $3CAA
#W32($3A30)
//・パーティーの全滅[END-FE]
・All party members die[END-FE]
```

Does anybody have some pointers/ideas on how to accomplish this using a Python script?

Comment: It's very easy to merge these two specific files but you need to think about what the rules are that define what goes where in order to develop a general solution. You'll also need to write some Python code

Comment: will the files always be so uniform?  as in the POINTER #3 in one file will always be on the same line as POINTER #3 in the other file?

Comment: @Alexander They are always uniform. The spaces are also always 5 lines long, which i didn't include in this example. On the Python Discord a nice person gave me this following example, which might work:

```
f1 = "1\n\n2\n\n3"
f2 = "a\n\nb\n\nc"
sep = "\n\n"

f1_chunks = f1.split(sep)
f2_chunks = f2.split(sep)

out_chunks = []
for num, letter in zip(f1_chunks, f2_chunks):
    merged = num + "\n" + letter
    out_chunks.append(merged)

merged_content = sep.join(out_chunks)
print(merged_content)
```
```
001 | 1
002 | a
003 | 
004 | 2
005 | b
006 | 
007 | 3
008 | c
```

Comment: It seems like Stackoverflow is unable to properly format comments, so here's the example using the 5 \n: https://pastebin.com/raw/QsjGN3Bc

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]; a question like this needs much more *focus* to suit this format. What is the rule that tells you that the lines `・Follower dies[NLINE]` and `・All party members die[END-FE]` should go in the first block? What should happen to the lines `//POINTER #3 @ $3BAC - STRING #3 @ $3E17` and `#W32($3BAC)` from the second file, and why? We cannot design an entire program feature for you here - please think about the logical steps to solving the problem and figure out exactly where you are stuck.

Comment: Please keep in mind that we are trying to build a library of searchable questions. Even someone who has the same overall task as this would not be able to search for it, because there are any number of things that "conditionally merge" could mean, and any number of rules that could be needed in order to get the right output.

Comment: Thank you very much Karl, i will try my best to adhere to the StackOverflow guidelines in the future! But honestly, not being able to properly add comments and edit comments at a later point in time is a pain in the ass.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will work...  I have already tested it.

```
import re

def match_line(line):
    match = re.match(r"//POINTER #(\d+).*?-\sSTRING #\d.*$", line)
    if match:
        return match.groups()[0]
    return False

def extract_file1(file1, file2):
    lst = []
    start = 0
    while start < len(file1):
        number1 = match_line(file1[start])
        if number1:
            temp1 = start
            while file1[temp1] != "":
                lst.append(file1[temp1])
                temp1 += 1
            extract_file2(file2, lst, number1)
            start = temp1
            lst.append("")
        else:
            start += 1
    return lst

def extract_file2(file2, lst, number1):
    for i, line in enumerate(file2):
        number2 = match_line(line)
        if number2 and number2 == number1:
            temp2 = i + 3
            while file2[temp2] != "":
                lst.append(file2[temp2])
                temp2 += 1
            break

def get_lines(path):
    return open(path, "rt", encoding="utf8").read().split("\n")

def main(path1, path2, path3):
    file1, file2 = list(map(get_lines,[path1, path2]))
    lst = extract_file1(file1, file2)
    with open(path3, "wt", encoding="utf8") as fd:
        fd.write("\n".join(lst))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    path1 = "file1.txt"
    path2 = "file2.txt"
    path3 = "file3.txt"
    main(path1, path2, path3)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! For the first few lines it worked perfectly, but after that it copies old data into new lines. Here is an example of what i mean:

File1: https://pastebin.com/Sn6TUyyC
File2: https://pastebin.com/s47JLYye
File3: https://pastebin.com/7A4NnB6B

At Pointer 11 it copied the first line:

```
//POINTER #11 @ $3A4C - STRING #11 @ $3DAD
#W32($3A4C)
//　[NLINE]
//ふとん犬はどこかへ走り去った…。[END-FE]
・All enemies defeated[END-FE]
```

Comment: @Murow  Sorry that is an easy fix though

Comment: @Murow  It should be fixed now